# Python Django - process long running views in the background

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio

What is the best approach to send a long running process to the background in Python when working within the Django framework.

Summary:
I'm using a Django web app alongside chatGPT to create a certain resource for my users. The problem is waiting on the response from openAI makes for a terrible user experience. For this reason I would like to offload this work. Ideally, I would like to send another http request to my server with the needed payload and run it in the background, then alert users when it's completed.

Here's the synchronous code

```
@login_required  
def createx(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'x/x_create.html', {})
    else:
        request_body = json.loads(request.body)
        #get user profile
        my_user = request.user
        #make sure the user is premium
        if not my_user.is_premium_user():
            #redirect to home page
            #set error message
            messages.error(request, 'You must be a premium user to create a x')
            return redirect('home')
        #get user profile
        my_user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=my_user)
        user_prompt = createPrompt(my_user_profile, request_body.get('position'), request_body.get('company'), request_body.get('description'))
        system_prompt = "You are a helpful assistant."
        #create x using chatgpt
        url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {settings.OPEN_AI_API_KEY}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

        # Craft the request payload
        payload = {
            "model": "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            "messages": [
                {"role": "system", "content": system_prompt},
                {"role": "user", "content": user_prompt}
            ],
            "temperature": 0.7,
        }
        # Send the request - would like to offload this request
        response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)

        # Handle the response
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        reply = data["choices"][0]["message"]["content"]
        return JsonResponse({'success':True, 'x':reply, 'prompt':user_prompt, 'system_prompt':system_prompt})
```

does anyone have any suggestions on how this could be done?

I have tried using asyncio to offload this network request, but I wasn't very experienced with that module and failed to get the result I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In general when we're dealing with long standing process tied to http requests we need to split up the work.

In your actual http request the only processing that should be done would be the minimum to return a response code.

Then you can offload the long standing portions [to a task queue like Celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html) or another system that can handle parallel processing. This is different than simply using an async view in the sense that the work has been handed off to a completely different distributed system that can still work on common datasets.

In order to update the user based on these long standing processes you'll need to integrate web sockets. [Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is a good starting point for setting this up but you can also do something like [directly integrate with socket.io](https://socket.io/) . Web sockets allow the long standing processes to finish and push results from the server to the client - bidirectional communication.